# What packaging option are available for python/django

Tags: python, django

I am starting on developing a django application on a shared webhosting server(alwaysdata.com).

I would like to understand what are the packaing options available to package a django application (preferably in compiled form)

I would like to setup the source code repository on my system and build using the python packaging and deploy the package on alwaysdata.com.
I would like the option of not having to share the source code on alwaysdata.com.
Looking at pip , I am not able to find this option.

EDIT
 A few more clarification: I would need the ability to not share the sourcecode since it contains the "API secret key" which I would not want to compromise. The more I look into it , the more i believe that there is no way for me to distribute binary only distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/index.html) to be a pretty nice tool for deploying Django projects. To compile your python code you can use [`compileall`](http://docs.python.org/library/compileall.html):

```
python -m compileall <dir>
```

Answer (score 1):

How is this API key used? Is it a google maps api? Is it provided in scripts that go to the browser?  If so, it's already out in the open, anyone using your site will see it, so you're trying to provide a $100 lock for a $0.01 piece of information.  If it's a google maps api, it's not secured by keeping it hidden, but rather it's tied to a domain/directory (IIRC).

Can you share a little more what the API key is and is for, then maybe we can help you find a better solution to keep it secure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think you have to share your source code if you host your application on a 'shared hosting' provider? That's not the case. Your source code should still be private to you but the administrators of your hosting provider can get it too. Other normal Joe Users of the service shouldn't have access to your source code, or your database too. If they do, then get another shared hosting provider!

Comment: I understand only the admin of webhosting will have access to source code. Actually I have got a paid google API key which is right now embedded in code. I am concerned about the API Key as getting that compromised means the stealer can use it to pose as myself. I know python supports built distribution . I am just not able to

Comment: Binary distribution won't help you - your API key has to be exposed at some point in order to work, and so however you obscure it in your code it will be visible to hosting administrators. If you don't trust the admins then you need to buy yourself a server, install the OS, give yourself the only account, and have it stored in a secure server location where only you have keys to the rack.

Comment: I understand only the admin of webhosting will have access to source code. Actually I have got a paid google API key which is right now embedded inside code. I am concerned about the API Key as getting that compromised would mean the stealer can use it to pose as myself. I will be happy if I can upload it as a built/binary package. I know python supports built distribution. I am just not able to find how to do that for django application.